# Why typeof undefined + 1 is a 'number'?

Tags: javascript

Im trying to pass the test of my lesson but answer of a test dont mach result im getting from JS Bin.
My task is:

```
let unknown = undefined;
let sum = unknown + 1;
let typeOfSum = typeof sum;
console.log(typeOfSum);
```

Answer of test should be 'NaN'

BUT!

When I'm trying this code in JS Bin, I get result 'number'

Please, help me to understand, why I'm not getting `NaN` if it should be `NaN`?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript works this way. There's no `typeof` output that's `NaN`. The answer is here:

[image: answer]

Yes, you're right. `undefined + 1` is `NaN`.

But `typeof NaN` is a `'number'` always.